# how to keep a odbc connection open in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to connect to a database and keep the connection open for any amount of user activity/queries within the database. Currently I have a connection that opens and closes for any query (save, update, etc...) which requires the logon process to the back-end every time the user saves etc... Is there a way to simply connect and leave the connection open so there won't be a lag time when running the query due to the logon process? This is what I'm using:

```
    Private sConStrFormat As String = "Provider=TDOLEDB;Data Source=TDDEV;Persist Security Info=True;User ID={0};Password={1};Default Database=bcpm_ddbo;Session Mode=ANSI;"


   Private Sub cmdsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdsave.Click


        Dim sSQL As String
        Dim sConStr As String

        Dim user As String
        Dim pass As String
        user = txtuser.Text
        pass = txtpass.Text

        Dim UserName As String = user
        Dim Password As String = pass

        sConStr = String.Format(sConStrFormat, UserName, Password)
        Using Con As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(sConStr)
            Con.Open()
            sSQL = "INSERT INTO LTC_FBS (CLM_NUM) VALUES ('" & Me.txtClaim.Text & "')"
            Dim cmdins As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sSQL, Con)
            cmdins.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Con.Close()

        End Using


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net automatically maintains a [connection pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502.aspx) for you. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.close.aspx#remarksToggle), when you call `Close()` on the `Connection` the framework

> releases the connection to the
>   connection pool, or closes the
>   connection if connection pooling is
>   disabled

Comment: so you are saying as long as i don't close the connection it will remain open and i can just use SQL = "....." anywhere in the app?

Comment: What I'm saying is that the first time that your app is used, the first SQL statement will connect to the server and execute. When you call close it doesn't actually close the database connection, it just releases it to the connection pool. The second SQL statement that gets executed (assuming the same connection string) will get reuse the connection from the pool without having to open it first. If your database has a way to monitor this you'll see that connections are actually constantly coming and going.

Comment: So keep coding the exact same way that you are now. You can read more about connection pooling and how to tweak it here: http://aspalliance.com/1099_Understanding_Connection_Pooling_in_NET.2

Comment: So i can still call Close() and it will remain pooled? so any lag after that is just the SQL, not the log-on etc...?

Comment: You are right! after that first connection, with the app open, i run again and it's instant... THANK YOU FOR THE CLARIFICATION!

Comment: One more question - will this hold true if i have a table adapter set up via wizard with a "non sensative" (no user/pass) connection string?

Comment: Connection pools are unique to connection strings so for every variation of connection string you have you'll have a separate connection pool. In your case you'll have two connection pools, one for the username/password connection string and one for the anonymous one.

Comment: Is there any way to do the same thing with the table adapter, or should i approach a new method of populating the form once it's opened (by unique identifier)? I've never populated a form using just SQL before, always a bound form.

Comment: Or the "  Me.LTC_FBSTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1TEST.LTC_FBS)" is what i've used... I'm assuming you can't define a connection here.

Comment: Connection pools are created for `Connection` objects. Somewhere along the way your `DataSet` is being loaded so somewhere there's a `Connection` object being created. That connection object will follow the same rules for connection pools in that it will share connections that use the same connection string.

Comment: gotcha... the hard part is that i can't insert variables into the app.config file which houses the connection string for the table adapter.

Comment: @gfuller40, don't worry, 2 connection pools is totally fine. Sure, each connection in the pool will incur overhead for connecting to the database the first time that its used but then it will be done. If you are overly concerned you could create a couple of connections to your database for each connection string in your application's startup to "prime the pool" but I really wouldn't worry about it. Also, if you're worried about performance I'd recommend using `SqlClient` instead of OLEDB if you're talking to SQL Server. But if you want to know about that you should create another question.

Comment: Thank you! i will open another question - unfortunately i'm limited to Teradata server.

Answer (score 1):

In vb.net 4.5 do the following:

At the top straight after the class definer put in this line:

```
    Public Shared conn As OdbcConnection
```

Then, in the subs where you want to use the connection use this line:

```
    If conn Is Nothing Then conn = New OdbcConnection(<your_connection_string>): conn.Open()
```

Then the New OdbcCommand will use the existing connection without opening a new one. Don't close the connection in your script until you are quite certain you're finished with it (_Shutdown is a good spot and you're good to go.

This also solves problems with MySQL when constantly opening new connections causes the max connections error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining 'con' in the using statement, define it up above as a static variable. When the function is called, you can see if 'Con' has been assined or not. If not, you build your connection string and set Con = New OleDBConnection, and open it. Since it's a static variable, it will retain its value at the next call. Check that it's not nothing, and then use it right away. Make sure you don't call close in the routine or the connection will not remain open.